# How to know on which page I am now

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a list of tabs, I want to know my current location for every time I click specific tab, I want my MainCTRL which is the father of all tab controllers to know which tab is active now.
I have tried to use ng-click event and using service such $location.path() to get current path. But first I get the previous path and not the current path.
I added the code below for demonstration and also a codepen:
http://codepen.io/Barak/pen/wGPpoZ

Why I need such feaure, because I want some common buttons of the header to be disable for specific group of the tabs and active for the other part of the tabs.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller("MainCTRL",["$scope","$location", function($scope,$location){
    $scope.title = "Hello World";
    $scope.onWhichPageIAM = function(){
      console.log("He click me");
      console.log("location:",$location.path());
      
      }
  
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<nav id="tabs_navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCTRL">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tabs-item">
            <a href="#/AnalyticsSummary" class="tabs-link">Analytics Summary</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-item">
            <a href="#/TDCG" class="tabs-link" ng-click="onWhichPageIAM();">TDCG</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-item">
            <a href="#/keygas" class="tabs-link" ng-click="onWhichPageIAM();">Key Gas</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-item">
            <a href="#/DuvalTriangle" class="tabs-link" ng-click="onWhichPageIAM();">Duval Triangle</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-item">
            <a href="#/DuvalPentagon" class="tabs-link" ng-click="onWhichPageIAM();">Duval Pentagon</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-item">
            <a href="#/NEI" class="tabs-link" ng-click="onWhichPageIAM();">NEI</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-item">
            <a href="#/PTX" class="tabs-link" ng-click="onWhichPageIAM();">PTX</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-item">
            <a href="#/GasTrends" class="tabs-link" ng-click="onWhichPageIAM();">Gas Trends</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-item">
            <a href="#/DataTable" class="tabs-link" ng-click="onWhichPageIAM();">Data Table</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-item">
            <a href="#/Playground" class="tabs-link" ng-click="onWhichPageIAM();">Playground</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-item">
            <a href="#/AnalyticsSettings" class="tabs-link" ng-click="onWhichPageIAM();">Analytics Settings</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That `ng-click` will fire on the page you're clicking, not the page it links to.  Have you considered simply checking `$location` inside `$routeChangeSuccess` (or inside the directive that draws the tabs)?

Comment: window.location.hash ? I am writing it on my mainCTRL of my angular app.

Comment: When to active window.location.hash ? onclick event?

Comment: No. Again, the ng-click will fire when the user clicks, not after the route changes.  Check the location after the route changes.

Comment: how can I sense that the route is change?

Comment: use the $location dependency. By using `$locaton.path()` you'll know on which page you are.

Comment: If you need something global, use `$routeChangeSuccess`.  It sounds like you could just check `$location` while drawing your tabs, though, in the directive link function or directly in the controller.

Comment: You can try with `$location.$$absUrl;`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for a ng-click, you can use the `$routeChangeSuccess` (@Daniel Beck suggestion) signal broadcasted on the `$rootScope`, use it like this:

```
app.controller("MainCTRL",['$rootScope', "$scope","$location", function($rootScope, $scope,$location){
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(ev, current, previous) {
    console.log("State change success");
    console.log("location:", current); // info referent to the current state.
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$state` variable to get the active tab.

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-radio="'mytabs'" ui-sref-active="active" ng-model="ActiveChild" ui-sref="tab1">FirstTab</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" uib-btn-radio="'mytabs'" ui-sref-active="active" ng-model="ActiveChild" ui-sref="tab2">SecondTab</button>

</div>
```

And use `$scope.ActiveChild = $state.current.name;` in your controller.

`$state.current.name;` should give you name of the active tab.

Comment: I don't use UI-Router

Comment: . controller("studentsController", function ($http, $route, $scope, $log) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        $log.debug("RouteChangeStart Event");
        $log.debug(event);
        $log.debug(next);
        $log.debug(current);
    });

    $scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        $log.debug("LocationChangeStart Event");
        $log.debug(event);
        $log.debug(next);
        $log.debug(current);
    });

Comment: Events like: `$routeChangeSuccess` or `$routeChangeStart` xD

Comment: http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2016/03/angularjs-route-change-events.html